# (Flutter) Huawei Location Kit - longitude and latitude null

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

I am trying to use Huawei Location Kit(Fused Location Service) to get longitude and latitude. But the response I get back are all null.

Then, I call the requestLocationUpdates() method to obtain the device location and update the cache. But I got PlatformException. May I know why?

[image]

[image]

My current code to use Huawei Location Kit:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Log:
[image]

Comment: If the system cache does not contain location information, the system returns a null value. so need to obtain location information through `RequestLocationUpdates`. The 10806 error indicates that the interface is not open to the public. Could you please post the screenshot of the invoking code and the parameter configuration of `locationRequest` to us for checking this issue?

Comment: Hi, I have updated my post with some screenshots of my code. Thanks. @shirley

Comment: According to the code provided above, no obvious problem is found. The local verification is normal. Could you kindly help us with some information to locate this issue?  1.The device model,OS, plug-in, HMS Core apk and Flutter version on which this issue happened. 2.the log obtained when the issues occurred.

Comment: I am running the application on a physical device. The model is Vivo 1716, Android OS, HMS Core apk version is 6.1.0.314, Flutter version is 2.2.3. The screenshot of the log is on the updated post above. I am not sure about the plug-in you required. @shirley

Comment: We provide the huawei Flutter plug-in of the location kit. Did you use it? If not, You could refer to [this document](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/HMS-Plugin-Guides-V1/introduction-0000001050191280-V1) to integrate.

Comment: I have already integrated the Huawei Flutter plug-in of location kit  @shirley

Comment: Since I still can't get the longitude and latitude using Huawei Location Kit, then is there other ways to get those that are able to use in on Huawei devices? @shirley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the new Location kit 6.0.0 version, Non-Huawei Android phones support only Fused location capability. [See Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/introduction-0000001050706106#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001050706106__section207491610112917).

In addition, only some interfaces are supported. [Docs link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References/location-description-0000001088559417#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001088559417__section7202105624412).

The `requestLocationUpdates` interface you use here is not supported by Non-Huawei Android phones. You are advised to use the `requestLocationUpdatesCb` interface instead.

Or you could use version `5.1.0.303` of the Flutter plug-in.

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code in the project, it seems working.

Can you check whether agconnect-services.json and key file is put in correct place like this:

Project screenshot:

[image]

and the API has been enabled in AppGallery Connect:

AGConnect Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Hi, the agconnect-services.json and key file are put as per your screenshot and the API is also been enabled in AppGallery Connect. But I still can't get null response and Platform Exception. @coollei